# structure of output __data.json sveltekit

Tags: svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

load in +layout.server.js generates */endpoint/__data.json. the structure looks like

```
{
   "type":"data",
   "nodes":[
      {
         "type":"data",
         "data":{ // some data }
         "uses":{
            "url":1
         }
      },
      null
   ]
}
```

For some reason i get null at the end of nodes. what does null mean in this structure? Can't find the explanation. Seems like this null appears only if load runs in +layout.server.ts

Comment: Why do you care? These are internals for the framework.

Comment: @brunnerh well what do you mean by "internals" ? i really do need to know why this null happens. I thought the logic is one node for each +(layout/page).server.ts in the route chain, but if it's true null came out of nowhere

Comment: "internal" means it's a file you are not supposed to mess with and should not need to concern yourself with either. Its structure and function hence is not documented. If you have a real, *observable* issue, open an issue on GitHub (unless the problem has already been reported).